# rootReducer = combineReducer produces type 'Never' with typescript

Tags: typescript, redux

When combining my reducers the type is setting the the root reducer to Reducer1: never, Reducer2: never

Example:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  stories: storyReducer,
  archivedStories: archiveReducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

*storyReducer (IStory[] , StoryActionTypes)

archiveReducer (number[], ArchiveActionTypes)*

The Type is instead coming out as,

stories: never;
archivedStories: never

I followed another stack overflow suggestion and tried to specify the type.

```
const rootReducer: Reducer<CombinedState<{stories: IStory[]; archivedStories: number[];}>, StoryActionTypes | ArchiveActionTypes> = combineReducers({
  stories: storyReducer,
  archivedStories: archiveReducer,
});
```

But its still trying to map them to Never

*Type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ stories: never; archivedStories: never; }>, FetchStoriesAction | AddStoriesAction | ArchiveStoryAction>' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<{ stories: IStory[]; archivedStories: number[]; }, FetchStoriesAction | AddStoriesAction | ArchiveStoryAction>'.
Types of parameters 'state' and 'prevState' are incompatible.
Type '{ stories: IStory[]; archivedStories: number[]; }' is not assignable to type 'CombinedState<{ stories: never; archivedStories: never; }>'.
Type '{ stories: IStory[]; archivedStories: number[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ stories: never; archivedStories: never; }'.
Types of property 'stories' are incompatible.
Type 'IStory[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)*

Whats the issue here? Or how can I specify the type correctly? My goal is to use .filter on the IStory[] payload.

These are the reducers:

Story Reducer

```
const INITIAL_STATE: IStory[] = []
  
const applyAddStories = (state: IStory[], action: StoryActionTypes) => action.payload;

export const storyReducer = (
  state = INITIAL_STATE,
  action: StoryActionTypes
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case STORIES_ADD : {
      return applyAddStories(state, action)
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Archive Reducer

```
const INITIAL_STATE: number[] = []

const applyArchiveStory = (state: number[], action: ArchiveActionTypes) => [
  ...state,
  action.payload,
];

export const archiveReducer = (
  state = INITIAL_STATE,
  action: ArchiveActionTypes

) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case STORY_ARCHIVE: {
      return applyArchiveStory(state, action);
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default archiveReducer;
```

Comment: What is the type of `action.payload` in `STORIES_ADD`? did you meant to add it to the array like you did in `applyArchiveStory`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd recommend enforcing the return type of your reducer. That's something I like to do, as it helps to type-check the reducer implementation:

```
//                                                           here
//                                                              v
function storyReducer(state: IStory[], action: StoryActionTypes): IStory[] {
  // ...
}
```

You won't need to explicitly type the reducer, it will just work with your original code:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  stories: storyReducer,
  archivedStories: archiveReducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

Here's a playground demonstrating the result: [link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYwiARsAdgUwEo4AmArsjlAM5wC%20cAZlGnAORRHEAezA3AFC-YY5OgEMycAJIBlGNACeiFBCxCVFAFxwKMKNgDmNPqiza4UgCoB5PBICiUgPoBBACIu4AXhYXrdx65ceXhg5MBwzWSg5J2QYYGVzUJwqLyQQsM10nAg6Mysbe2c3ABo4MBE5ABsIEUJNaUi5AG0AXUN%20Y1MJADkJcwknABkHCydzW3qZeVbPOFbeODheTvgRMDBK6MJCKd1k2YAKbREhScbW0rE45U1d6Nj4rESwigBKTwA%20OCvHgDpyqo1Qh8Xg4DiQWBKEzwbTyAgkMhQQ4LLQwE7hLw9PoDYajcbFFE-G4ReQxa5PJIUXjvM7TNoeL4IFEUADuwBgyAAFnADkSsL8su8mYtFsgRBRwj4Cv43HBNMKRYs2DBiFAsN91psnNtdsBkkc0UJLg9lK8UYtqOa4IQcKJiJUYOorUqcCq1aj0XwLbxqCCVnBGBAYPDSORZqgMNh8OxERQDgrYXsNKi4THyATqK8QWCIfAsnA8BAgzJ0bMCG6KWEADxZHIBovBtNQD5%205SmY5CWaBxsI8gHLD2ypZ-gdnC-RN6ihNAAMLV%20xlUMAoQA)

Comment: Ive added the reducers to the original question, maybe that will help shed a light on what Ive done wrong. As for using any, I was able to do the following, export type RootState = any instead of export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>; which allows all the code to run and allowed me to confirm it works without issues. This is just a toy build to validate TypeScript can be used in a larger project.

Comment: @Terry, unfortunately, the part you added about the reducer (the signature) won't help understanding the inferred return value. Have you tried typing the return value of your reducer? That might help.

Comment: Even when I specify this, it still complains that it is never. Reducer<CombinedState<{stories: IStory[]; archivedStories: number[];}>, StoryActionTypes | ArchiveActionTypes> Its as if I cant overide the never []. I have also tried using an array inside an object instead of the state being an array but same issue. ** I have expanded the reducer code

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a playground link. Feel free to edit it if you still have a problem.

Comment: That was it, I misunderstood. Thanks!

Comment: The type of `RootState.stories` would be `never` in case of `function storyReducer(state: IStory[], action: StoryActionTypes): (IStory[] | null) { ... }`. This can be avoided by not using `null` of course, but sometimes you want indicate that something is not there, e.g. *no user -> user = null;*.

Comment: very nice suggestion @FábioBatista. in my case, when i tried to reinforce the output type, i got an error in one of my cases payload. so i could find out where i had typed it wrong. thanks for your helP!

Comment: It did not work for my unless I made state optional, so `(state: IStory | undefined, ...)`.